# Is momentum flux scalar or vector?

Tags: momentum, gauss-law, navier-stokes, transport-phenomena

I'm trying to derive Navier Stokes equation and stacked the linear momentum equation below. The second term is momentum flux, but it seems scalar value for me because it is vector times vector. How can I interpret this equation to understand momentum flux is vector?

$$\frac{d(\rho\underline{v})}{dt}
+\nabla\cdot(\rho\underline{v}\underline{v})
+\nabla\cdot\underline{\underline{\sigma}}
-\rho\underline{g}=0$$

Comment: The inside qauntity is a TENSOR. I am  not familiar with tensors however from the other things in your equation it has to be. In the standard mass conservation equation there is $\rho \vec{V} $which has units $ \frac{kg}{m^2 s}$ this quantity is dotted with the differential element da in a closed surface to find the component of mass directly leaving the surface. Multiplied by da to find the amount of mass directly leaving the volume through the surface boundary.  This is done similarly for momentum but the qauntity is $(\rho\vec{V})\vec{V} $ then the last velocity is purely dotted with da

Comment: To then find the component of this tensor in the direction of da, aka the component of this tensor directly leaving these surface. This tensor from easy unit analysis has units kg*(m/s) 1/m^2  which is momentum per unit area per second, so times by da is the total momentum leaving the surface per second

Comment: My advice for you is when learning these equations look at the integral form

Comment: By the way: The preferred way here to show equations
is [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).
Since you are new here, I've replaced your image by this.

Answer (score 1):

The $\underline{v}\underline{v}$ is meant to be the
[outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) of $\underline{v}$ and $\underline{v}$,
thus giving a tensor (i.e. a thing similar to $\underline{\underline{\sigma}}$).
More often this is written as $\underline{v}\otimes\underline{v}$
or $\underline{v}\underline{v}^T$
(see for example [Navier-Stokes equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations#General_continuum_equations)).

In Cartesian coordinates this is the $3\times 3$ matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}
v_xv_x & v_xv_y & v_xv_z \\
v_yv_x & v_yv_y & v_yv_z \\
v_zv_x & v_zv_y & v_zv_z
\end{pmatrix}$$

So finally, the term $\nabla\cdot(\rho\underline{v}\underline{v})$
is the inner product of the vector operator $\nabla$
and the tensor $(\rho\underline{v}\underline{v})$,
thus giving a vector, which is consistent with the other terms
of the equation.

Comment: Note: if $\underline{v}$ is a column vector then the inner product is $\underline{v}^T \underline{v}$ and the outer product is $\underline{v} \,\underline{v}^T$, where all the standard rules of matrix multiplication apply (i.e. a $3 \times 1$ thing can multiply a $1 \times 3$ thing and the result will be a $3 \times 3$ thing.

Comment: This notation seems to have been not widely taught but since it is entirely logical, it is good know I think. (The corresponding quantities in Dirac notation are $\langle v | v \rangle$ and $| v \rangle \langle v |$).

Answer (score 1):

The term $\nabla \cdot (\rho \vec v \vec v)$ is the rate of loss of momentum per unit volume due to fluid flow; it is a vector.

For two vectors $\vec r$ and $\vec s$, $\vec r \vec s$ is a tensor whose array components by row in Cartesian coordinates $1, 2, 3 $ are: $(r_1s_1 \enspace r_1 s_2 \enspace r_1s_3), (r_2s_1 \enspace r_2 s_2 \enspace r_2s_3), (r_3s_1 \enspace r_3 s_2 \enspace r_3s_3)$.

See discussions in the text Transport Phenomena by Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot.